# Cloud Composer scheduler error when adding first dag

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG running on my local Airflow.
I lunched Cloud Composer and wanted to move my DAGs there.
When added the first DAG file the scheduler shows this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 363, in process_file
>   m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source module =
>   _load(spec) File "", line 684, in _load File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked File
>   "", line 674, in exec_module
>   File "", line 781, in get_code
>   File "", line 741, in
>   source_to_code File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/testdag.py", line 95 'start_date': datetime(2018, 12, 05),

This is line 95:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 12, 05),
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}
```

Never encountered this error before.

Comment: Are there log lines before or after the one you pasted that might be relevant? Since there's not much to go off of in that traceback, I have to ask the obvious question: are datetime and timedelta properly imported in your DAG definition?

Comment: @Wilson This dag works perfectly in my Airflow installed on EC2 server for 4 months. I wanted to move my dags to cloud composer. I moved the dag and it generated this error. It doesn't indicate a problem with packages. I never saw this error before nor found info on google so I don't know how to debug it. This error doesn't appear on regular Airflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the DAG's and do catchup from the historical dates then you give the past dates as `start_date`

Try giving

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'provide_context': True,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.combine(datetime.today(),datetime.min.time()),
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the DAG logic. It works on regular Airflow but dosen't work on Cloud Composer. I want to understand why

Answer (score 0):

May its the date value you gave in start_date. 
Try providing just `5` in `datetime(2018, 12, 05)` and update the DAG folder again.